# How can I include two classes in each other?

Tags: php, methods, include, require

Let´s say I have **two PHP classes** one called **gallery** and one called **image**.

In the class image I want to include the class gallery, and in the class gallery I want to include the class image.

How could this be properly done - or whats the best way to accomplish this?
What I want to be able to do in the end is to use methods of the class gallery in some methods of the class image.

**For example:** I have a method "delete" in both classes. **In the class gallery** the method is used to delete a specific gallery - selected by id. But **in the class image** the method delete also checks if the deleted image was the last one in a gallery - if so this gallery should be deleted by passing the id to the delete method of the class gallery.

How could this be done best? - Or is there a complete different better way of doing something like this?

Thanks for your anwers!

Comment: `class image extends gallery`?

Comment: I think you want `require_once`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composition .. the `image` instance has an instance of the gallery that it belongs to (if it can belong to multiple galleries that complicates things).

```
class Image {
   private $gallery;
   private $db;
   public function __construct(Gallery $gallery, DB $db) {
      $this->gallery = $gallery;
      $this->db = $db;
   }

   public function delete($id) {
      $this->db->deleteImage($id);
      if ($this->gallery->isEmpty()) {
         $this->gallery->delete($this->gallery->getID());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am new to OOP but your answer definitly showed me the right direction to take.

Answer (score 0):

Make your gallery the only place to instantiate the image class, and then set a property in the image's constructor for the gallery to pass in a reference to itself.

eg:

```
// in class Image
...
function Image($gallery) {
    $this->gallery = $gallery;
}
...

// in class Gallery
...
function get_image($id) {
    $img = new Image($this);
    ...
    return $img;
}
...

$image = $gallery->get_image(1);
```

**edit:**
looks like ExplosionPills beat me to the punch with a better example

Comment: I would also suggest not using `new Image` .. you know, design to an interface blah blah.

Comment: Yeah. I'm just writing as I remember it. I actually don't like PHP and don't use it anymore.